# Увеличивается background-image при раскрытии меню

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

В мобильной версии сайта, при нажатии на бургерную иконку, раскрывается меню и увеличивается `background`, когда закрываешь меню, `background` возвращается в исходное состояние. В чем может быть причина? Свойства `background`- а:

```
body {
  background-color: #333d5f;
  background-image: url("../img/Background.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  background-size: auto;
}
```